# Bootstrap 5 dropdown navigation menu doesn't work in asp.net core mvc razor layout page

Tags: drop-down-menu, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-5

I am working on an asp.net core mvc project and i have a dropdown navigation menu in my index page. I wanted to convert that index page into a layout page but when I tried to convert that into a layout page, dropdown stopped working for me. It was working perfectly fine while using in index page only, but when I tried to convert that into a layout page, it somehow stopped working. please help.
Here is the code for the layout page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/fontawesome/css/all.css" />   
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid p-4 text-white" style="background-color:forestgreen;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="~/images/logo.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" /></td>
                <td><h1>Derawala Education & Charitable Trust</h1></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid align-content-center">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Apply For A Scholarship
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" asp-action="Apply">Apply With Registered School/College/University</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" asp-action="ApplyUNR">Apply With Unregistered School/College/University</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Donate Now</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-action="AppStatus">View Application Status</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Registration
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" asp-action="RegSCU">School/College/University</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" asp-action="RegDonor">Donor</a></li>
                        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-action="SignIn">Sign In</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-action="AdminPanel">Admin Panel</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>
    <div>
        <main role="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `data-toggle="dropdown"` to replace `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"`.

Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid align-content-center">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Apply For A Scholarship
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" asp-action="Apply">Apply With Registered School/College/University</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" asp-action="ApplyUNR">Apply With Unregistered School/College/University</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Donate Now</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-action="AppStatus">View Application Status</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Registration
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" asp-action="RegSCU">School/College/University</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" asp-action="RegDonor">Donor</a></li>
                        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-action="SignIn">Sign In</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-action="AdminPanel">Admin Panel</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I tried that.. but doesn't work for me